# SocialAuth-Android Couldn't find the URL

Tags: java, android, social-networking, socialauth

I use library socialauth to authorize login to social network. A few day it work normally after i replace file jar from ***socialauth-android-2.0.jar*** to ***socialauth-android-2.1.jar*** but now i test again it not work and show error:  `org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError: Couldn't find the URL.`

Could you tell me some solution please? Have other Java library that can use to auth to social network and get profile information like this lib? (only Facebook and Twitter is enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i can find solution by [socialauth-android](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) website. Update file jars and get the last version.

Comment: Hi , please mail your stacktrace in case you still find any issues.

Comment: Ok! i will when i have problem.